# HTTP Response CSV not downloading

Tags: java, http, csv, servlets

So in my JAVA controller I have:

```
    response.setContentType("text/csv");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;   filename=\"export.csv\"");

    try {
        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        String outputResult = "xxxx, yyyy, zzzz, aaaa, bbbb, ccccc, dddd, eeee, ffff, gggg\n";
        outputStream.write(outputResult.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

Here is the inspect element network tab: [image]

Under the response tab I see the csv text just like it should display.

Comment: Please explain the wanted behavior

Comment: @omerts Should pop up the save dialog box and save the csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're trying to use Content-Disposition with content requested using XMLHttpRequest. That doesn't work.

Comment: So what should be done instead?

Comment: I don't believe there's anything that would affect the behavior of a request sent through XmlHttpRequest.